# What does 'them' refer to in the passage, 'people' or 'the individual'?

Tags: usage, pronouns

If ***them*** refers to ***people*** in the previous sentence, it - the sense of belonging and interdependence among members - makes people feel less accountable for it(the offense), which I think doesn't make sense. Or, if ***them*** refers to ***the individual*** in the following clause, I think it makes sense. But can the pronoun refer to the following noun? In adverbial, it can, but I am not sure it can in this context.

> In my research with Liane Young and James Dungan of Boston College, we
> studied the effects of loyalty on people using Amazon’s Mechanical
> Turk, an online marketplace where users earn money for completing
> tasks. At the beginning of the study, we asked some participants to
> write an essay about loyalty and others to write about fairness. Later
> in the study, they were each exposed to poor work by someone else.
> Those who had received the loyalty nudge were less willing to blow the
> whistle on a fellow user for inferior performance. This finding
> complements research showing that bribery is more common in countries
> that prize collectivism. The sense of group belonging and
> interdependence among members often leads people to tolerate the
> offense. It makes ***them*** feel less accountable for it, diffusing
> responsibility to the collective whole instead of assigning it to the
> individual. In short, empathy for those within one’s immediate circle
> can conflict with justice for all.

[HBR's 10 Must Reads Big Business Ideas Collection](https://In%20my%20research%20with%20Liane%20Young%20and%20James%20Dungan%20of%20Boston%20College,%20we%20studied%20the%20effects%20of%20loyalty%20on%20people%20using%20Amazon%E2%80%99s%20Mechanical%20Turk,%20an%20online%20marketplace%20where%20users%20earn%20money%20for%20completing%20tasks.%20At%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20study,%20we%20asked%20some%20participants%20to%20write%20an%20essay%20about%20loyalty%20and%20others%20to%20write%20about%20fairness.%20Later%20in%20the%20study,%20they%20were%20each%20exposed%20to%20poor%20work%20by%20someone%20else.%20Those%20who%20had%20received%20the%20loyalty%20nudge%20were%20less%20willing%20to%20blow%20the%20whistle%20on%20a%20fellow%20user%20for%20inferior%20performance.%20This%20finding%20complements%20research%20showing%20that%20bribery%20is%20more%20common%20in%20countries%20that%20prize%20collectivism.%20The%20sense%20of%20group%20belonging%20and%20interdependence%20among%20members%20often%20leads%20people%20to%20tolerate%20the%20offense.%20It%20makes%20them%20feel%20less%20accountable%20for%20it,%20diffusing%20responsibility%20to%20the%20collective%20whole%20instead%20of%20assigning%20it%20to%20the%20individual.%20In%20short,%20empathy%20for%20those%20within%20one%E2%80%99s%20immediate%20circle%20can%20conflict%20with%20justice%20for%20all.)

Comment: It refers to people who prize collectivism.

Comment: Isn't ***it*** in 'less accountable for it' refer to the offense, the bribery?

Comment: Yes, it means people who prize collectivism feel less accountable for the offense of bribery.